# Баг с js, textarea, как решить?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Короче, я сделал форму отправки сообщения. В ней сделал див с изображениями (эмоджи). 
К каждому изображению добавил onclick='smiles("тут id эмоджи")'
И всё роботало вроде нормально, при нажатии на какое-то изображение, он добавлял в форме в textarea айди смайла
Но проблема в том что, если я нажму на это изображение, уменя вставится  id в textarea, и я что-то впишу, потом опять нажму на изображение, то id не будет вставлятся. ПОЧЕМУ?
Вот сам код, он сокращён, без html, body, head
https://pastebin.com/XsC8M35Q

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function smiles(id) {
    $("textarea[name='message']").append(id);
  }
</script>
<form action="code.php" id="sender" method="POST" name="form_send_message">
  <textarea name="message" minlength="0" maxlength="255" placeholder="Введите сообщение" required><?php echo $_SESSION['msg_mess_err']; unset($_SESSION['msg_mess_err']); ?></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" name="recipient_id" />
  <input type="submit" name="btn_send_message" value="Отправить">
  <br/><br/>
  <div id="smiles">
    Нажмите на эмоджи чтоб его выбрать<br/>
    <img src="/images/smiles/1.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml1]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/2.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml2]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/3.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml3]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/4.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml4]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/5.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml5]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/6.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml6]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/7.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml7]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/8.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml8]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/9.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml9]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/10.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml10]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/11.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml11]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/12.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml12]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/13.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml13]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/14.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml14]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/15.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml15]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/17.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml17]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/18.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml18]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/19.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml19]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/20.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml20]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/21.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml21]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/22.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml22]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/23.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml23]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/24.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml24]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/25.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml25]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/26.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml26]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/27.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml27]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/28.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml28]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/29.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml29]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/30.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml30]");'>
    <img src="/images/smiles/31.gif" onClick='smiles("[sml31]");'>
  </div><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: Переформулируйте вопрос, приведите самодостаточный [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  и [как задать хороший вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), а ваша ссылка нерабочая, для просмотра требует регистрацию

Comment: Я обновил, ссылку, теперь должо роботать

Comment: выложи пример кода суда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я воспроизвёл Ваш пример. Через инструменты разработчика видно, что id смайлов добавляются в тег textarea в любом случае, видно их в поле для ввода текста или нет. Причина такого поведения в том, как браузер связывает значение полей формы и текст внутри тега textarea (это не совсем одно и то же). В какой-то момент браузер заполняет поле своего внутреннего объекта-формы текстом из textarea и больше не следит за текстом внутри тегов. Когда Вы что-то печатаете в поле для ввода текста, браузер изменяет значение этого объекта формы у себя в памяти. В инструментах разработчика хорошо видно, что введённый вручную текст не появляется между тегами, в то время как на странице он есть. Таким образом, изменять надо значение элемента формы, а не текст внутри тегов. Для этого надо использовать jQuery-метод val().

```
var text = $("textarea[name='message']");
text.val(text.val()+id);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я попробую

Comment: Всё заработало, спасибо.

Comment: Раз мой ответ Вам помог, то отметьте его как решение, пожалуйста.